# Calculate columns from multiple CSV files and save results into a new file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, math

I'm new to Python and trying to do the following with python/pandas.

I have four CSV files that look like this (the only difference is the date value in the first column):

First_week.csv:

```
     date       id   name   total_unitCount   total_orderCount   total_invoiceCount
  2020-02-12     1   Guitar        300              600                   500
  2020-02-12     2   Drums         500              600                   500
  2020-02-12     3   Piano         700              1000                  400
```

Second_week.csv:

```
     date       id   name   total_unitCount   total_orderCount   total_invoiceCount
  2020-02-05     1   Guitar        300              800                   500
  2020-02-05     2   Drums         500              300                   500
  2020-02-05     3   Piano         700              350                  400
```

I need to calculate the % difference between two numbers in each csv file/between each weeks (first_week.total_orderCount vs second_week.total_orderCount, second vs third, third vs fourth):

Example of calculation:
`Difference = ((total_orderCount[where date is 2020-02-12] - total_orderCount[where date is 2020-12-05] ) / Units[where date is 2020-12-05]) * 100%`

Then save results to a new CSV file for each week (here I provided results only for the week1vsweek2):

```
    id   name   %difference_week1vsweek2  %difference_week2vsweek3  %difference_week3vsweek4
    1   Guitar             -0.25                          
    2   Drums                1                       
    3   Piano               0.65
```

Would someone be able to help or give me some step by step instructions? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what defines week 1 vs week n ?

Comment: What have you done so far? Maybe you could start by reading the csv files into one or multiple dataframes...

Comment: Your calculation formula seems to be incorrect, please check whether it is correct. Also the dates in your `first_week.csv` are greater that dates in your `second_week.csv`, check whether the csv files are named correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo-code on how to do column calculations from multiple CSV files and save the results to a new file using pandas in python is

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('First.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Second.csv')
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["col1", "col2"])
output_df['result'] = df1['col2'] -df2['col2'] # some column calculation
df3.to_format("output.format")
```

Here is the actual code for the given example in the Question

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd

#read files
df1 = pd.read_csv('First_week.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('Second_week.csv')

#Create new file and save results
column_names = ["id", "name"]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
df3[['id', 'name']] = df1[['id', 'name']]
df3['%difference_week1vsweek2'] = (df1['total_orderCount']-df2['total_orderCount'])/df2['total_orderCount']*100
print(df3)

df3.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is very helpful! Thank you! However, for most values calculation is correct, but for some values it calculates wrongly example:  `df3['%difference_week1vsweek2'] =(2-3)/3*100` this calculation would return 1.0 as its result and not -0.33. Would you know what can cause this?